# What happens to expired items on announcement list on sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

What happens to expired items on announcement list on sharepoint? 
Can i get all items include the expired items?

Answer (score 6):

Nothing happens to them as such - they are just filtered out of the display using a View with a Filter.

This is the filter used :-
[image: Announcements fitler]

You get to it by

- Edit Web Part
- Edit the current view

Comment: Hi , there is no filter on  the default view ( allItems ) , there is any work around that i need to do to see those items ?

Comment: There is no filter on the default view and that is why you can actually SEE the expired items - have you looked? The web part you see on the home page doesn't use that. It uses a filter of Expires = <BLANK> OR Expires >= TODAY.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is even if you modify the current view, expired list hides for my account. But say in an organisation where there are too many user where i need to make this view similar to what i see in my local administrator account.

At the moment i can able to hid the expired list under my administrator account but if i log in to normal account user i can still see the expired lists.

Since if thats the case ic ant go and ask all the users do the same

Answer (score 0):

I changed the drop down option from Expires (indexed) to Expiration Date and assigned the formula it seems to be working for all users. Not sure what the difference though.

More over also noticed that i need to publish even after applying and click OK to that current view which is bit inconsistent in SharePoint where in some places you don't have to do this.